# ColdFusion and trailing comma

Tags: coldfusion

How do I remove a trailing comma from a string in ColdFusion?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To remove a trailing comma (if it exists):

```
REReplace(list, ",$", "")
```

To strip one or more trailing commas:

```
REReplace(list, ",+$", "")
```

Comment: I tried a general replace first, but when I do that, it of course removes "all" commas in the string.  I only want to remove that trailing one.

Answer (score 15):

Also easy:

```
<cfset CleanList = ListChangeDelims(DirtyList, ",", ",")>
```

Explanation: This takes advantage of the fact that CF list functions ignore empty elements. `ListChangeDelims()` consequently strips off that last "element".

Answer (score 5):

Check the rightmost char - if it's a comma, set the string to a substring of the original, with length -1.

Trimming the string ensures that spaces after the trailing comma don't interfere with this method.

```
<cfset myStr = "hello, goodbye,">
<cfset myStr = trim(myStr)>

<cfif right(myStr, 1) is ",">
    <cfset myStr = left(myStr, len(myStr)-1)>
</cfif>
```

Comment: after trying Patrick's Reg Ex below, it did exactly what I needed in MUCH less code, thanks again.

Comment: Patrick's is much the better answer alright - mine is more of quick hack. Glad it got sorted for you either way!

Answer (score 4):

This is probably more of a performance hit than Regex'ing a list, but sometimes when I end up filtering/fixing dirty data, I convert it to an array and then convert it back into a list.

```
<cfset someVariable = arrayToList(listToArray(someVariable, ","), ",")>
```

It's cheating, but it works ;-)

Comment: Cheating it may be... but it's just solved my problem after a couple of hours of pissing about... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To add onto Patrick's answer. To replace one or more commas at the end use the following:
reReplace(myString, ",+$", "", "all")

Example Below

```
<cfset myString = "This is the string, with training commas,,,">
<cfset onlyTheLastTrailingComma = reReplace(myString, ",$", "", "all")>
<cfset allTrailingCommas = reReplace(myString, ",+$", "", "all")>
<cfoutput>#onlyTheLastTrailingComma#<br />#allTrailingCommas#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove "," from Both Sides, Just the Right Side, or Just the Left Side

```
<cfset theFunnyList = ",!@2ed32,a,b,c,d,%442,d,a">
```

Replace Funny Characters and Separate with Comma

```
<cfset theList = rereplace(theFunnyList, "[^A-Za-z0-9]+", ",", "all")>
<cfset theList = trim(theList)>
<cfif left(theList, 1) is "," and right(theList, 1) is ",">
  <cfset theList = right(theList, len(theList)-1)>
  <cfset theList = left(theList, len(theList)-1)>
<cfelseif right(theList, 1) is ",">
  <cfset theList = left(theList, len(theList)-1)>
<cfelseif left(theList, 1) is ",">
  <cfset theList = right(theList, len(theList)-1)>
</cfif>
```

Sort List (Numeric to A-Z) ASCending

```
<cfoutput> #ListSort("#theList#", "text", "ASC", ",;")# </cfoutput>
```

Comment: Richard, welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for the contribution. You can format code by indenting four spaces.